# Настройка xdebug + phpstorm на удаленном сервере

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

Установлен xdebug на рабочий сервер, настроен phpstorm. В настройках показывает всё хорошо. Но на брекпоинты не реагирует. Идентично поднял сайт на локалке, xampp. Настройки те же,  тот же брекпоинт ловит.
В php.ini прописан

```
zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so
zend_extension_ts = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6_ts.so
zend_extension = "/etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = myip
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

Пробовал
`xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1`, прописав  `ssh -R 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 username@remote_server`

Результата нет. В phpstorm всё классно в настройках, на локальном сервере отлавливает, на удаленном нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Mapping неправильный, скорее всего.

Comment: когда mapping неверный, при валидации ошибку пишет

Comment: Про валидацию в вопросе ни слова.